# alternatives to using make as a script runner

Tags: make, gnu-make

**tl;dr**
`make` is working for me, but I'm looking for the appropriate tool.

I'm currently using `Makefile`s as script runners for my projects. In order to standardize each project, I just create a makefile so that I can write things like:

```
make setup
make teardown
make execute "SOMETHING"
```

In this case, `setup` might pull and deploy a bunch of docker containers, `teardown` might clean them up, and `execute` would run a command against a container.

I'm not using `make` to actually build things with dependencies. This makes me think I'm just being very hacky...but hey, it's worked so far.

I don't think `make` is the right tool for this job, but I don't know if there's some other common binary that allows people to just run `xyz command`, where `xyz` would be make in this case. I don't want to write a new bash script for every project, since that's generally much less readable imo.

Things I don't like are when `make` spits out:

```
make: *** No rule to make target FOO. Stop.
```

This is usually when I abuse `make` to process args (e.g. `make execute "do this in a container"`).

Does anyone have suggestions on a common unix tool that would allow me to just specify some commands to run?

Comment: "Does anyone have suggestions on a common unix tool that would allow me to just specify some commands to run?" ... yes, and that is called a script. If you do the same things often, you might even be able to generate them.

Comment: so, is your question "how to use targets containing spaces in GNU make?"

Comment: Make is really powerful for dependency based scripts (*recompile x if y has changed*) and therefore very good at building things.  If you're not particularly using this feature then the most likely answer is **"any programming language"**. Scripting languages such as shell (`bash`) and `python` are generally the default choice for this type work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simple with a script like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

function execute {
    echo "Executing $1"
}

case "$1" in
    "setup" )
        echo "Setting up" ;;
    "teardown" )
        echo "Tearing down" ;;
    "execute" )
        shift
        execute "$@"
        ;;
    * )
        echo "Usage: ..."
esac
```

The usual caveats with shell scripts apply (take care with variable expansions, error handling).